# Injecting xml file into spring bean

Tags: java, spring, file-io

I am trying to read xml file from remote location in my DAO.

```
<bean id="queryDAO"
      class="com.contextweb.openapi.commons.dao.reporting.impl.QueryDAOImpl">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="myDS"/>
  <property name="inputSource" ref="xmlInputSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="fileInputStream" class="java.io.FileInputStream">
  <constructor-arg index="0" type="java.lang.String"
                   value="${queriesFileLocation}"/>
</bean>
<bean id="xmlInputSource" class="org.xml.sax.InputSource">
  <constructor-arg index="0" >
    <ref bean="fileInputStream"/>
  </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

I am able to read XML for first time. For subsequent requests, inputstream is exhausted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `FileInputStream` thats where the problem lies. Once you have read the data in the stream there is no way you can read the contents again. The stream has reached its end.

Solution to this problem would be to use another class `BufferedInputStream` which supports resetting of stream pointing to anywhere in the file.

Following example shows that `BufferedInputStream` opened only once and can be used to read the file multiple times.

```
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream (new FileInputStream("test.txt"));

        int content;
        int i = 0;

        while (i < 5) {

            //Mark so that you could reset the stream to be beginning of file again when  you want to read it.
            bis.mark(0);

            while((content = bis.read()) != -1){

                //read the file contents.
                System.out.print((char) content);
            }
                System.out.println("Resetting ");
                bis.reset();
                i++;

        }

    }
```

There is catch. Since you are not using this class yourself but dependent on `org.xml.sax.InputSource` to do it, you need to create your own `InputSource` by extending this class and override `getCharacterStream()`  and  `getByteStream()` methods to `mark()` `reset()` the stream to start of the file.

Answer (score 2):

Hope you know that in spring, by default all bean objects are singleton. So try to mention fileInputStream and xmlInputSource as non-singleton by setting the field `singleton="false"` in those bean declarations.

Comment: But I want to load xml only once. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try inlining the FileInputStream so it forces a new instance each time?

```
<bean id="queryDAO" class="com.contextweb.openapi.commons.dao.reporting.impl.QueryDAOImpl">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="contextAdRptDS"/>
    <property name="inputSource">
        <bean class="org.xml.sax.InputSource">
            <constructor-arg index="0" >
                    <bean class="java.io.FileInputStream">
                        <constructor-arg index="0" type="java.lang.String" value="${queriesFileLocation}"/>
                    </bean>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```